# Is it possible to add an auditor peer in corda?

Tags: corda

I would like to add some sort of an auditor peer in corda. Is it possible with my use case?:

Currently the network has two peers: partyA and partyB. There are about 100 transactions involving both parties. Lets say later on a partyC (the auditor) joins the network: is it possible to give partyC access to all of those already posted (and future) transactions in the ledger involving partyA and partyB?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the observer nodes feature. See the tutorial [here](https://docs.corda.net/tutorial-observer-nodes.html) and the Observable States sample [here](https://github.com/corda/samples).

In your case, you need the following flows for `partyA` or `partyB` to send all the past transactions to the auditor when the auditor first joins the network:

```
@InitiatingFlow
@StartableByRPC
class SendAllPastTransactionsToAuditor : FlowLogic<Unit>() {
    @Suspendable
    override fun call() {
        // We extract all existing transactions from the vault.
        val transactionFeed = serviceHub.validatedTransactions.track()
        transactionFeed.updates.notUsed()
        val transactions = transactionFeed.snapshot

        // We send all the existing transactions to the auditor.
        val auditor = serviceHub.identityService.partiesFromName("Auditor", true).single()
        val session = initiateFlow(auditor)
        transactions.forEach { transaction ->
            subFlow(SendToAuditorFlow(session, transaction))
        }
    }
}

@InitiatingFlow
class SendToAuditorFlow(val session: FlowSession, val transaction: SignedTransaction) : FlowLogic<Unit>() {
    @Suspendable
    override fun call() {
        subFlow(SendTransactionFlow(session, transaction))
    }
}

@InitiatedBy(SendToAuditorFlow::class)
class ReceiveAsAuditorFlow(private val otherSideSession: FlowSession) : FlowLogic<Unit>() {
    @Suspendable
    override fun call() {
        // We record all the visible states in the transactions we receive.
        subFlow(ReceiveTransactionFlow(otherSideSession, true, StatesToRecord.ALL_VISIBLE))
    }
}
```

Then for all subsequent transactions between `partyA` and `partyB`, you need to do the following to notify the auditor:

```
@InitiatingFlow
@StartableByRPC
class RegularFlow : FlowLogic<Unit>() {
    @Suspendable
    override fun call() {
        val transaction: SignedTransaction = TODO("Regular flow activity to agree transaction.")

        val auditor = serviceHub.identityService.partiesFromName("Auditor", true).single()
        val session = initiateFlow(auditor)
        subFlow(SendToAuditorFlow(session, transaction))
    }
}
```

Alternatively, `partyA` and `partyB` could extract all the past transactions from their node's database, and send them to the auditor directly. The auditor can then check the transactions and their signatures off-platform.