# Display information on a non-participant page in corda

Tags: corda, states

There is a super admin node and 3 party nodes. They are connected in a localhost network. The super admin is not a participant in any of the states, but still needs to view all information of all the states. Is this possible? If yes, how?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to add an auditor peer in corda?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49217202/is-it-possible-to-add-an-auditor-peer-in-corda)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Joel's comment above is accurate, what you really want to think about is an observer node. The idea is straightforward enough, the node is simply observing all of the transactions.

Here's an example cordapp on GitHub that uses the observable states feature: 
https://github.com/corda/samples-java/tree/master/Features/observablestates-tradereporting

I'd also look at the StackOverflow answer from Joel that he linked to: [Is it possible to add an auditor peer in corda?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49217202/is-it-possible-to-add-an-auditor-peer-in-corda)